# MongoDB combine 3 collections

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query

i have 3 collections:

restaurants: [Restaurants](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nEVvk.png).

menu: [Menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8xGmL.png).

products: [Products](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bkMGc.png).

product has '_id' Menu, Menu has '_id' restaurant.

And at the end I want one collection that has all this data joined:

```
'_id'
'hours': {
     'everyday'
     'twentyFourHours'
     'text'
     'intervals':[{
               'day'
               'start'
               'end'}...]
 'image'
 'phones'
 'takeAway'
 'name'
 'description'
 'address'{...}
 'user'
 'menu'[{
      'name'
      'products':[{
               'price'
               'image'
               'name'
               'description'
        }...]
}
```

How can I combine 3 collections by restaurant id?

Comment: You need to use aggregation pipeline with `$lookup`. Check this: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/ or more advanced https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#join-conditions-and-uncorrelated-sub-queries

Comment: @DheemanthBhat Hello, thanks for the answer, i will try to do this